# gsoap how to prevent underscore translation for enum values

Tags: gsoap

Is there a way to influence which textual values are used in the soap messages generated by gSoap? To be compatible with existing clients I need the soap service to use identifiers with underscores but gsoap uses dashes.

Part of declaration in input file for soapcpp2

```
enum class ns1__resultCode
{
    OK, ///< xs:string value="OK"
    ERROR_INVALID_SESSION,  ///< xs:string value="ERROR_INVALID_SESSION"
    ...
};
```

When server sends ERROR_INVALID_SESSION the soap message contains ERROR-INVALID-SESSION but I need this to be ERROR_INVALID_SESSION because that is what existing clients expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscores in C/C++ names are translated to hyphens in XML as a gSOAP convention. I've understood that hyphens are (or were) more common in XML than underscores, and that is why. For names in XML to have underscores instead of hyphens, use `_USCORE`: `ERROR_USCOREINVALID_USCORESESSION` becomes `ERROR_INVALID_SESSION` in XML. Also dots are translated this way, e.g. `ERROR_DOTINVALID_DOTSESSION` becomes `ERROR.INVALID.SESSION`.  Other characters are encoded with _xHHHH, e.g. `ERROR_x002fINVALID_x202fSESSION` becomes `ERROR/INVALID/SESSION`. This covers Unicode code points up to U+FFFF.

Of course, instead of using an enum that requires C/C++ names to be translated to XML, one can use a (wide) string and use any Unicode code points.